# Entity Core and SaveChanges works only once

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have problem with Entity Core 3.1.2.

I have code like this:

```
SQL.Database.EnsureCreated();
var ThisCollector = SQL.CollectorServers
                       .Where(esa => esa.ServerName == ServerCollectorName)
                       .FirstOrDefault();

while (foo)
{
    await SQL.Entry(ThisCollector)
             .ReloadAsync();
    DateTime dtTimeOut = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1);    
    //check status of current Worker
    var CurrentLB = SQL.CollectorServers
                       .Where(esa => esa.isWorker == true 
                                    && esa.LastSeenLB < dtTimeOut)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
    if (CurrentLB!=null) //Current Worker is dead!
    {
        CurrentLB.isWorker = false;
        ThisCollector.isWorker = true;
        SQL.SaveChanges(); //This works allways
    }
    var Collectors = SQL.CollectorServers
                        .Where(Esa => Esa.isWorker == true);

    if (Collectors.Count() == 0) 
    {
        ThisCollector.isWorker = true;
        SQL.SaveChanges();
    }
    if (Collectors.Count() >= 2) 
    {
        foreach(CollectorServer cs in Collectors)
        {
            cs.isWorker = false;
            //why this is requied?
            SQL.Entry(cs).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified; 
        }
        ThisCollector.isWorker = true;
        //<--This works only once, without manually setting State to 
        // modified!!! Why? Values has been changed from external program. 
        //(Management studio in this case)
        SQL.SaveChanges();      
    }
    await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
}
```

Problem is that last SaveChanges works only first time it has been called without I set Entry state to Modified. After that it does not make SQL query (I can see that in SQL Profiler).

In this case this can be fixed by this way, but I'm trying to undestand why this happends. My software saves lot data to SQL, and I need to know can I trust to this code without opening all queries and adding this modified state.

I didin't have this kind of problems in full version (6) of Entity, this is something quite new for me.

Comment: `SaveChanges` works just fine. This code doesn't make a lot of sense though. A DbContext is a unit of work, not an alternative for SqlConnection. It's not meant to be kept around (neither is SqlConnection). `SaveChanges` persists all the changes in a UoW and is typically call right before exiting eg an action and disposing the `DbContext`. If you don't call it, you get "automatic" rollback as no changes are stored. Any new modifications after `SaveChanges` **are** tracked too.

Comment: DbContexts are *not* thread-safe because they aren't meant to be used from different threads - there's no point when only `SaveChanges` is going to write to the database. Everything else is an in-memory operation.

Comment: What is this code doing anyway? What is `SQL`, what are those `Entry` calls ? You do realize that `Collectors` is *not* a list of objects but a query? Every time you enumerate it or call `Count()` on it, it runs again.

Comment: I suspect it's a lot easier to do what you want with one or more `UPDATE` queries. An ORM like EF is meant to Map Objects to Relational tables. You don't have objects here, so there's no need for an ORM.

Comment: Yup, code may not make lot of sense, lot of stuff cutted off. Only problematic code left. SQL is DbContext, and it's used only in this thread.

Entry calls, someting new to me in Core Entity. (MSDN "The entry provides access to change tracking information and operations for the entity.")

Actualy that Count is good point, I will fix it.

Comment: The entire code is problematic and extremely hard to understand. *What does it do*? If you wanted to implement a queue over a table, you can only do so with raw SQL, with *very* careful locking hints. Or use "destructive reads", a `DELETE TOP 1 OUTPUT deleted.ID` that returns the single deleted item's data. That's the same as a `pop` operation on a queue

Comment: If you want to modify the earliest/latest record in a table, a) you're asking for a queue and b) unless you can do that in a *single* statement, you need a transaction. In any case, using a proper SQL statement would take only a few lines, be a lot faster, safer *and* easier to understand

Comment: What code does is not important, it probably will change. I just wanted to know can I trust to this DBContect.SaveChanges(), and now I feel that I cannot. (Atleast without lazyloading). You are correct that I should use direct SQL queries in this case.

Comment: It's quite important - this code is very hard to read and understand. Right now only you can debug it and see what it does. Everyone else has to guess what each query does, or how the multiple iterations of the same query would affect EF. In normal EF code, the context would be created and disposed *inside* the loop at least

Comment: How is `CollectorServers` defined? Does it use `AsNoTracking` perhaps? You can enable [EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) to see what's going on inside EF, not just the query text. For some reason, the entities returned by `Collectors` aren't tracked

Comment: And `await SQL.Entry(ThisCollector)` probably *attaches* `ThisCollector` after each iteration, right before reloading it with `ReloadAsync`. So the various `SaveChanges()` calls aren't really different. In all cases, the entities get re-attached before they get modified

Comment: PS you still haven't posted the DbContext code. That would show immediatelly whether `CollectorServers` is tracked or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described behavior would make sense if the entities returned by `CollectorServers` are *not* tracked.

`ThisCollector` is *attached* on every loop by the call to `SQL.Entry(ThisCollector)` :

```
await SQL.Entry(ThisCollector)    //Attaching
             .ReloadAsync();      //Reloading
```

Any changes made to it would be tracked and saved by the first call to `DbContext.SaveChanges()`.

On the other hand, the entities returned by the `Collectors` query :

```
var Collectors = SQL.CollectorServers
                    .Where(Esa => Esa.isWorker == true);
```

Would remain *un*tracked, until they get reattached by the call to `SQL.Entry(cs)` :

```
foreach(CollectorServer cs in Collectors)
{
    cs.isWorker = false;
    SQL.Entry(cs).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified; 
}
```

That's equivalent to calling [DbContext.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-3.1) to attach and set the state to `Modified`. Update is easier to read though :

```
foreach(CollectorServer cs in Collectors)
{
    cs.isWorker = false;
    SQL.Update(cs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your opening reply. This clarified a lot.